# TexStudio does not generate bibliography

Tags: xetex, biber, friggeri-cv

I'm making my CV by using the template found here:[friggeri](https://it.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv). Since I need to print all my publication, I've used the command `\nocite{*}`, but when I open the pdf file there isn't any publication. I'm working on Windows 10 with texstudio, and I've configured xelatex and biber as required by the template.
The funny thing is that if I compile my CV on sharelatex it works!
How can I resolve?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome!  Please show us a short, **compilable** code (without personal informations!). Then we can test your code on own computers and check the error messages and warnings.  BTW: do you get warnings and error messages (see `*.log` and `*.blg` file) ...  Add the first error and warning to your question please.

Comment: Additionally to configuring your editor to use `biber` you have to actually call `biber` by pressing `F11` (default).

Comment: Just for posterity: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) and [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)

Answer (score 1):

As @Johannes_B suggested, I ran Biber using the appropriate command. The steps I used are:

1. F6 for generating necessary files
2. F8 (instead of F11) for making bibliography
3. F6 twice for generating the pdf with the bibliography.

Thanks to you all for the support!

Comment: I'd just like to note that according [some](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/184051/35864) [documentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156206/35864) I found on this site and [elsewhere](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~mbayat/hacks/tag/texstudio/) F11 is indicated as the default bibliography shortcut, [but the help page says its F8](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html) (of course that can be changed, and it could be that the default is system-dependent, maybe it has to do with https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/1272/).